# Image not showing in Imageview(inside Fragent,inside ViewPager in Tabbed Activity)-Picasso not replacing placeholder

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a tabbed Activity, each tab containing a Fragment with a recyclerView. An item in the recyclerView is composed from an Image with a text, both fetched from Firebase real time database.

Everything seems to be working fine with no errors however when I run the app, the name is fetched and displayed, the image not.

Help?
Thank you in advance!

[image: firebase structure]

[image: emulator showing name but not image]

Here is the fragment

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.andrei.bucatariadebuzunar.Clases.ImageUploadInfo;
import com.andrei.bucatariadebuzunar.Clases.ImageUploadInfoViewHolder;
import com.andrei.bucatariadebuzunar.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FripturiFragment extends Fragment {


    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ImageUploadInfo> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageUploadInfo,ImageUploadInfoViewHolder>adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Recipes_Images").child("Fripturi");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRecipes);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        LoadData();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ImageUploadInfo>().setQuery(databaseReference,ImageUploadInfo.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageUploadInfo, ImageUploadInfoViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageUploadInfoViewHolder imageUploadInfoViewHolder, int position, @NonNull ImageUploadInfo model) {
                imageUploadInfoViewHolder.textView.setText(model.getImageName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.hat).into(imageUploadInfoViewHolder.imageView);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ImageUploadInfoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_card_view,parent,false);
                return new ImageUploadInfoViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Picasso doesn't recognize this URL format, so it won't be able to show the image.

```
StorageReference ref = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

storageRef.child("Recipes_Images").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
       //set your image
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```